# FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 62: Call to undefined method App\User::create()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to register users in Laravel 5.1 using registration out of the box.
I did exactly everything in this [tutorial](https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/)

When I fill my register form and submit, I get:

> FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 62: Call to undefined method App\User::create()

The method is a built-in method in Laravel 5.1:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([  // <!-- it fails here
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);
}
```

Any idea?

Here is my `routes.php`, in case:

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
//
//
// Password reset link request routes...
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
    Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
    Route::resource('competitors', 'CompetitorController');
    Route::resource('grade', 'GradeController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('country', 'CountryController');
    Route::resource('places', 'PlaceController');
});
```

And my `AuthController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Registration & Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
| authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
| a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
|
*/

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
private $redirectTo = '/';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

    ]);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the create() method in your routes.php ?

Comment: What happens if you do store it inside `$userData` and do `User::create($userData);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My User Model was not extending Model! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1 :**

You should define `create` method inside your route

`Route::post('create', 'yourController@create');`

**Issue 2 :**

I guess you're mixing get and post, If you're using get method then you need to pass all the data via url which seems not good, i recommend you to use `post` method instead, so i wrote the route in post method

```
public function create() 
{
$userData = Input::except('_token');
User::create($userData);
}
```

**Warning :** You're not validating your input

You can do this by creating

```
$validation = Validator::make($userData, User::$userData);
if ($validation->passes()) 
{
//do Create Action here and return success
}
{
//return failure messages to view
}
```

and you can define your `$postData` rule  inside your `User` Model.

**Update :**  As i find that you're using default `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` thanks to [Thomas Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145624/thomas-kim) for pointing it.

Inside your create() method

You shall get the inputs and print like this to test

```
$userData = Input::except('_token');
return $userData;
```

And then make it done (insert)

```
User::create($userData);
```

Hope this help you

Comment: He's using the default AuthController, which has the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. That trait does validate the input, and it has a `postRegister` method, which calls the `create` method that creates the user.

Comment: Ah, i didn't noted it, I will change the answer accordingly. Thanks :)